# Finding the voltage across nodes A and B

Tags: voltage

[image: The above image is the circuit]

I've tried solving it and have managed somehow to make out the answer but it isn't in a systematic way.

[image: This is how I did]

Comment: What’s the question?

Comment: Check your first line again. X is half way around the 2 A loop so ...

Comment: Didn't understand

Comment: Your Vax is incorrect. I suggest you start by calculating the voltage across all of the resistors, being careful to mark the **polarity** of the voltage.

Comment: there is no equation for Vyb on your worksheet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your simplified schematic is incorrect. You can't ignore the 6-ohm resistor.

The key point to realize is that there can be no current through the 5-V source and 10 ohm resistor, because there is no return path for that current. That lets you calculate the potential difference between X and Y very easily.

Potential differences A-X and Y-B can be found by applying KVL on the two loops in the circuit.

Comment: But when I take the two loops separately I ain't getting both the variables in one equation

Comment: @James Poutil. You can figure out the voltage drop across the 5V battery and 10 ohm resistor from V = IR, where I = 0.

Comment: @JamesPoutil, you just need to figure out \$V_{AX}\$ on one side and \$V_{YB}\$ on the other. Hint: The work you showed gets this wrong. The path from A to X only goes through one resistor, not two.